Disambiguate [jai] (Java Advanced Imaging API) from the Jai programming language
Proposal

Rename jai to advanced-imaging-api or java-advanced-imaging-api
Introduce jai-lang or jai

Details
I've been part of the Jai programming language closed beta for a while now and I thought about laying the groundwork here on Stack Overflow by posting questions with answers to common problems with the Jai language. With the goal for people to quickly be able to resolve their common issues once the language is available to the public. I noticed this same approach when I started with the Rust language a couple years ago and I was really thankful for the people who put in the work.
Problem
The tag jai already exists and it is associated with a Java API. It doesn't seem to receive much traffic, but it will cause confusion with the Jai programming language in the future.
I haven't checked all jai posts, but given the beta state of the language, I would assume that there aren't any tags to be cleaned up. I also expect traffic on the new tag to be very low until its beta state is lifted.
Questions

Is it acceptable to create a new tag for a language in closed beta?
What are your thoughts on my naming proposal?

Resources

https://github.com/Jai-Community/Jai-Community-Library/wiki
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/advanced-imaging-api.html


[[tag:jai-lang]] would certainly make more sense for the new tag, as it's unambiguous. Otherwise you could easily find that once [[tag:jai]] is renamed, you start getting questions about the Java Advanced Imaging API for a tag about the language. It would, however, likely be beneficial to make [[tag:jai]] a synonym of one of tags (probably the existing [[tag:jai]]).

"Is it acceptable to create a new tag for a language in closed beta?" Is it imminently coming out of the closed-beta? If not, then though I would suggest it's on-topic I would question the "usefulness" of questions on a language that no one but a small few have access to (or even awareness of).

@ThomA It is currently unknown when the beta state will be lifted. The language has been in development since 2014 and the beta is running since 2020. There are already published games built in jai by beta users. But there are still changes and features coming to the language.

it seems a good idea to create [java-advanced-imaging-api], and then make [jai] a synonym to avoid any future confusion with [jai-lang] however it's not necessary (although not harmful either) to immediately create [jai-lang]. At your reputation level, you can create that tag when the time comes by simply asking an on-topic question and tagging it with [jai-lang].

@blackgreen What is the rule behind making a tag a synonym? Programmers in the game development industry associate the name "jai" with the programming language (it's been talked about for 10 years at this point even if it still in beta). It therefore seems counter intuitive to me to link [jai] (with just over 300 questions) to a Java library when [jai-lang] will probably quickly exceed the traffic of the current [jai] tag after the beta lift. I would probably just remove [jai] to remove the confusion.

A tag synonym is not set in stone. However right now there is no issue with that tag, because nobody is attempting to ask jai-lang questions on Stack Overflow. At this time it's reasonable to expect that more people will attempt to tag [jai] a question about the Java library than the other way around. I.e., the [jai] -> [java-advanced-imaging-api] synonym can prevent the mis-tagging which right now is more likely to happen. When and if the traffic to [jai-lang] overtakes that of the Java library, the synonym can be switched over.

Let me make a statement here; Jai, as in Java Advanced Imaging, is pretty much a ghost in the shell at this point. It was a wild ambition from Sun Microsystems way back when that has since then been superseded at least twice over, including by an API built into the JDK itself. Oracle just seems to want to keep it around for nostalgia reasons I guess. Just let the jai programming language have its jai tag in my opinion and let it be consistent with other programming language tags which do not have a '-lang' in the name. There will be no people using the tag for Java-based questions.

@Gimby RE: consistency with other programming language tags, there are at least two precedents, [tag:nim-lang] that even has [nim] as a synonym, and [tag:crystal-lang]

Well lets not make breaking consistency a trend.
